# How do I convert a county name into it's corresponding FIPS code?

Tags: r

I have a fairly large dataset in which I'm trying to create a function that will change a county name into it's corresponding FIPS code. A sample of my function in R would look as follows...

```
    county2FIPS <- function(county){
    county <- as.character(county)
    county(
"11111" = county == "Davis",
"22222" = county == "Jefferson",
"33333" = county == "Washington")
    }
```

But whenever I then try to use the function (example below) on my data set I get an error saying that R "could not find function county".

`data$FIPS <- county2FIPS(data$county)`

I'm sure I've misclassified something somewhere and just can't see it, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

The expected result of course was to change all of the county values into the corresponding 5 digit FIPS codes.

Comment: when you write `something()` r will parse `something` as a function. b.t.w., the package **tigris** might have implemented what you need already.

Answer (score 0):

use the functionbelow:

```
county2FIPS <- function(county){
   c(Davis = "11111",
     Jefferson = "22222",
     Washington = "33333")[as.character(county)]
}
```